# Failed to start websocket connection

Tags: jenkins, websocket, jenkins-pipeline, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jgit

When I execute my Jenkins pipeline, during the repository clone stage, it crashes and the error message is:

> Failed to start websocket connection io.fabric8.kubernetes.client

Not sure if it's because of the way I am cloning the repo or a VPN issue (as I am working on a company laptop which uses a company VPN).

Changed the way I cloned the repo, used both HTTP and SSH. Currently I am cloning the repo like this in the pipeline: `sh "git clone -b BRANCH_NAME REPO_URL"`

Comment: Not a git question

Comment: Yes, while it is not a direct git question, I am using git commands to clone the repo in Jenkins, not sure if that qualifies for me to use the 'git' tag tho LOL

Comment: What is the "caused by" from your error messages? For instance, [this log](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/hono-dev/msg01755.html) shows a similar error caused by Error 500.

Comment: Jenkins has its own built in (non-Git) code, which is what you are using here. That code is what wants to create a websocket connection from the https session. (This may be part of jgit; I changed the tag.)